# Connect Odoo with another PoS

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

One of my client have been using `XYZ PoS`. Now they need to connect it with Odoo accounting module. When they create a record in their pos immediately affect in odoo.

I need suggestion  about following steps:

1. Ask them to modify their code to connect with odoo using WEB API. (Are they going to do this?)
2. Create a CRON job and pull the records from their database to odoo and create corresponding records in odoo.

Let me know if any other solution is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the my suggestion for your questions

1) Ask them to modify their code to connect with odoo using WEB API. (Are they going to do this?)

```
Yes they have to do some changes to connect with odoo.You can suggest theme to use XML RPC to connect with odoo , or you can write some REST API as per the requirement.
```

2) Create a CRON job and pull the records from their database to odoo and create corresponding records in odoo.

```
In my opinion you can do realtime syncronization if possible (It may slow down your process) or as you said CRON Job is also a good solution.
```